# Shopp Catalog Shortcodes on Wordpress

Tags: slug, shopp

I'm using Shopp on a Worpress site, and would like to pass two slugs in one shortcode instead of two shortcodes.

Right now, this is how it's displayed:

```
[catalog-collection slug="holiday-gift-cards"]
[catalog-collection slug="holiday-platters"]
```

Is there a way to get both of those into one shortcode? I'd like to display them that way so they come in after one another instead of breaking into a different row on top of each other.

I can't find any syntax online of how to do it, so if anyone knows how, any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comment turned out to be an answer, I'll repost here for future reference in case others might have the same question:

If you're going to use Shortcodes for this, the [Shopp Shortcode Documentation](https://shopplugin.net/docs/the-catalog/shortcodes/) has a slug called 'tag'. If you apply a tag name of 'holiday' to all of the products you want to combine, you can have a shortcode of just `[catalog-collection slug="tag" tag="holiday"]`